# How can I throwError with an rxjs Observable in this case?

Tags: rxjs

I have code like this:

```
loadImageFile(url: string, progressCallback: (progress: number) => void): Observable<string> {
  return new Observable<string>(observer => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const nativeWindow = this.windowRef.nativeWindow;
    let notifiedNotComputable = false;

    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    xhr.onprogress = event => {
      if (event.lengthComputable) {
        const progress: number = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
        progressCallback(progress);
      } else {
        if (!notifiedNotComputable) {
          notifiedNotComputable = true;
          progressCallback(-1);
        }
      }
    };

    xhr.onloadend = function() {
      if (!xhr.status.toString().match(/^2/)) {
        // Here I want that the user of the Observable created at the top with
        // "return new Observable" can use "pipe(catchError(...))".
      }

      if (!notifiedNotComputable) {
        progressCallback(100);
      }

      const options: any = {};
      const headers = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();
      const m = headers.match(/^Content-Type:\s*(.*?)$/im);

      if (m && m[1]) {
        options.type = m[1];
      }

      const blob = new Blob([this.response], options);

      observer.next((nativeWindow as any).URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      observer.complete();
    };

    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

How can I make the `xhr.onloadend` act so the `Observable` returned by this `loadImageFile` method will `throwError`?

I believe my issue is that I am already inside `new Observable`, while it's the main function `loadImageFile` that should `return throwError`.

How can I overcome this?

PS: Please ignore this text: StackOverflow won't let me post this because it's mostly code, but in this case, I believe it makes sense, so I'm just writing this paragraph here to make the post validation pass :)

Thanks!

Comment: You can call `observer.error()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

`observer.error(xhr)`